# Right justification of div using CSS

Tags: html, css, positioning, justify

The Image attached is what i am trying to accomplish!

[image: What i am trying to accomplish]

Now here is my codePen example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/leEdg

I cannot change the placement of the circle cause that is being animated on a path and has to stay where it is. What i want to do is be able to move the .stepInfo over to justify it correctly. Now the text that comes after the little line ball guy is dynamic and will be a variable size. So fixed width might not be the right answer.

Any help will be GREATLY appreciative! Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Just to clarify terminology, do you mean "align" which is well alignment, or ""justify" which is a given line is filled with no space on the left or right of the line?

Comment: Like this? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AGfhe

Comment: I did indeed mean align. How do i get the text to appear in one line though? I have to specify a width for that to happen no? THANK YOU btw

Answer (score 0):

So here is what I think will work out for you! I floated the text to the right, but that is only a minute problem to other things. Going through your code, I found 'pt' instead of 'px' which is fine but just stay consistent going through. Another thing, if you adjust the padding of the step label, it will adjust the positioning. So in a new, revised [codpen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/CjEnu), I did that for you :) If you have ANY questions, just leave a comment and I can try to help explain as much as possible.